# format date to datetime format in R

Tags: r

I have a good one this time. I need to combine `df$Date` and `df$Time` to `Date_Time` as below:

```
df
   Date      Time   Date_Time
    1/2/2012   9     1/2/2012 9:00:00
    1/3/2012   2.3   1/3/2012 2:30:00
    1/4/2012   8     1/4/2012 8:00:00
```

I am doing this but this code is not working right.

```
    df$Time<-gsub( '\\.', ':', df$Time)
    df$Time <- paste(df$Time, ":00", sep='')
    df$Date_Time <- paste(df$Date, df$Time, sep=' ')
    df$Date_Time<-strptime(df$Date_Time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Is there an easy and better way to convert `date` to `datetime` regardless of having complete `H:M:S` at the end?

Basically, if the `Date_Time` is like this:

```
1/1/2012 9 or 1/1/2012 9.3
```

Is there way to convert this data to datetime format in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just do `strptime(paste(df$Date, format(df$Time, nsmall=2)), format='%m/%d/%Y %H.%M')`

Edit: changed `nsmall` to 2

Comment: I think nsmall should be 1 "the minimum number of digits to the right of the decimal point"

Comment: That doesn't give you what you asked for in your question. Maybe you meant for the second `Date_Time` in `df` to have '2:03:00' instead of '2:30:00'?

Comment: No, I need df$Date and df$Time combined to be like df$Date_Time.